# Breaking long macro argument list in GNU assembler for AArch64

Tags: assembly, macros, arm64, gnu-assembler

I'm writing assembly code targeting ARMv8 (AArch64) in GNU assembler. Not sure if it matters, but I'm coding directly in my ARMv8 target (a Raspberry Pi board) running Linux.

I have a macro with a **very** long argument list (as in, over 60 arguments) -- I know, this is just wrong, please don't shoot me.

For readability, I'd like to break this argument list over multiple lines, i.e. something like this:

```
.macro my_macro arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4,
                arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8,
                // ...
                arg61, arg62, arg63, arg64

    // macro code goes here

.endm
```

I'd also like to do the same when instantiating the macro.

Unfortunately, as soon as I try to insert a line break in the macro declaration, I get the following error:

```
test.s: Assembler messages:
test.s:123: Error: Bad parameter list for macro `my_macro'
```

As for inserting a line break in the macro instantiation, although I don't directly receive an error, the code doesn't assemble because all parameters after the line break are ignored, i.e. as though I had instantiated the macro with fewer parameters than it expects, so the missing ones default to an empty string.

According to [the manual](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/AArch64_002dChars.html):

> The ‘;’ character can be used instead of a newline to separate statements.

I tried to add a `;` to the end of each line, i.e.:

```
.macro my_macro arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, ;
                arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, ;
                // ...
                arg61, arg62, arg63, arg64

    // macro code goes here

.endm
```

This made no difference. Same thing for a line break in the macro instantiation. I also tried other characters, such as `#`, `@` and `//` with no luck.

So: is it possible to insert line breaks in the middle of the argument list in a macro declaration or instantiation?

Comment: Did you try backslash \ like in C?  Semicolon can be used *instead* of a newline, so either one would be a problem, and you're using both.  Semicolon has uses like `.byte 1 ; .word 2` in a packed struct or something.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that, even though it was the first thing I tried, even before looking at the manual. Adding a backslash results in a "Warning: stray `\'" message, as well as the same errors already mentioned.

Comment: People often write assembler source that is to be run through the C preprocessor before being passed to the assembler.  The `gcc` command does this automatically if you name your file as `foo.S` with an uppercase S.  And the C preprocessor does handle backslash line continuation, so that the assembler would just see one long line.

Comment: It also gives you the option to use C-style `#define` macros, in case that would serve your purposes better than an assembler `.macro`.

Comment: Asm macroses supports iterations. As an option you probably could create a macros that would generate a list of `args` with as many numbers as needed. Sorry, have not done that for ages and could not give an example out of a head.

Comment: @NateEldredge changing the file extension to .S and using backslashes solved my problem. Will you make into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know a way to do this in the assembler itself.  However, a common practice when writing Unix-style assembly is to run your source through the C preprocessor before passing it on to the assembler.  It's common enough that the `gcc` command will do it for you if you give your source file a name ending in `.S` with an upper case S.

The C preprocessor does support backslash line continuation, so in that case you can write

```
.macro my_macro arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4,     \
                arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8,     \
                // ...
                arg61, arg62, arg63, arg64  

    // macro code goes here
.endm
```

and the whole `.macro` directive will be seen as a single line by the assembler.

Having the C preprocessor also gives you the ability to use C-style macros with `#define`, in case that is useful.